# How to list all values from column then list after checking in subquery without repeating?

Tags: mysql, sql

fairly simple question here but I haven't been able to find an answer after searching for a while.

I have two tables, hotel_room and guest.

Each guest has an ID that is also stored in the hotel_room table.

I want to pull a list of all guest IDs and also all guest IDs that are in a big hotel room. So far, I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT guest.guestid AS all_guestid
     , hotel_room.guestid AS guestid_big
  FROM guest
     , hotel_room
 WHERE hotel_room.guestid IN(
SELECT DISTINCT guest.guestid
FROM guest
JOIN hotel_room ON guest.guestid = hotel_room.guestid
WHERE room_size = 'big');
```

However, this results in something like:

```
all_guestid|guestid_big|
-----------+-----------+
1          |1
2          |1
3          |1
4          |1
5          |1
1          |3
2          |3
3          |3
4          |3
5          |3
1          |5
2          |5
3          |5
4          |5
5          |5
```

and so on. Basically, the guest_big value just repeats instead of only listing each number once. I'm assuming this is because I have to use hotel_room.guestid in the where statement versus guest.guestid? Is there a way to do this so it only returns every value once (e.g., just NULL in the guest_big column after it lists them all instead of listing each value with every all_guest value?) Thanks so much!

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select guest.guestid AS all_guestid , big_guest.guestid
FROM guest LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT guest.guestid
FROM guest
JOIN hotel_room ON guest.guestid = hotel_room.guestid
WHERE room_size = 'big') big_guest
ON  guest.guestid.big_guest.guestid
```